# change the height and color of listview items ? (android)

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I have a `listview` which include 4 items, I just need to increase the height between items? and also how can I change the items color.

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to your items - this will increase distance between them. If you need to change colour - set background colour of your item' view.

Answer (score 0):

to add some space use padding or margin

e.g if You want to add 10dp padding and 10dp margin

```
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
```

if You want to change background colour or text colour

```
android:background="#c5e1b0"
android:textcolor="#898989"
```